# Can I and how to protect my react-router routes with laravel passport

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router, laravel-passport

I can't find docs for react and laravel authentication, but I saw in forums that people are using passport and so I used it too. Currently I have access_token, I can guard laravel routes with passport's middleware, but how do I protect react-router route?

currently I am thinking of using 
Cookies from 'universal-cookie' to pass token as cookie to admin dashboard component and from there to run axios request in order to check whether token is valid. If access would be granted I could display the dashboard, other way to display "access denied" element. But this isn't route protection, I would like to know how to do it properly

```
 var bodyFormData = new FormData;
        bodyFormData.append('name', this.state.name);
        bodyFormData.append('password', this.state.password);
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/login',
            data: bodyFormData,
            config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                var cookies = new Cookies();
                cookies.set('access_token', response.data.access_token, { path: '/' });
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                alert(response)
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the way this is done is by wrapping the standard `Route` component with a a custom one, and handing your auth logic there.

See this post for a good example: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: This looks promising, If I'll manage to combine it with passport's auth I'll mark it as accepted. Currently I am thinking to store passport's token into a cookie after successful auth, then redirect to PrivateRouter and make axios get request with token in order to check the user, then corresponding to axios response I'll display admin dashboard or redirect to login page if unsuccessful.